# Slide animation between views of a ViewFlipper

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-animation

In an Activity I have the following:

```
var flipper = FindViewById<ViewFlipper>(Resource.Id.flipper);
flipper.Touch += flipper_Touch;
```

The basic implementation of the touch handler looks like this:

```
float oldTouchValue = 0;

void flipper_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
{
    var flipper = sender as ViewFlipper;
    switch(e.Event.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            oldTouchValue = e.Event.GetX();
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            float currentX = e.Event.GetX();
            if (oldTouchValue < currentX)
            {
                flipper.ShowNext();
            }
            else if (oldTouchValue > currentX)
            {
                flipper.ShowPrevious();
            }
            break;      
    }
}
```

This allows me to navigate between the different views but I'd like to make it slide left/right

I've seen some Java examples on how to make it work, but not direct way to translate it to c#.

What's required to make the views slide and is there a way to define the `animation` in `XML`?
I'm able to make Activities slide in and out using `animations` defined in `XML` and calls to `OverridePendingTransition`, but I'm not sure how to apply that knowledge here.

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı thnx for the edit... I actually did not know how to highlight words like that, learned something new thnx :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> This allows me to navigate between the different views but I'd like to
>   make it slide left/right

The `ViewFlipper` has, through its `ViewAnimator` class, some methods to set the animation for the in and out actions, [`setInAnimation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setInAnimation%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) and `setOutAnimation()`. This are in the Android SDK but should have correspondence in MonoDroid(with which unfortunately I'm not familiar so I could be wrong). In order to have the desired animation simply use the two methods above to set the desired animations(either xml file or programmatically built `Animation`) and then call the `showNext/Previous` methods like you currently do.

You even have some slide animation in the Android SDK, but again I don't know if they are present in MonoDroid.

**Update**: Those methods are indeed available in Monodroid and exposed like this:

```
//Using one of the built in animations:
flipper.setInAnimation(this, Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft);
flipper.setOutAnimation(this, Android.Resource.Animation.SlideOutRight);

//Using custom animations defined in XML
flipper.setInAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.slide_in_right);
flipper.setOutAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.slide_out_left);
```

Comment: @Lukesprog Your info made me find what I need in Monodroid. I did not want to post my own answer as I want to mark yours as the answer (don' want to steal it from you) so I edited your answer to include what I've found in MonoDroid, I hope you don't mind. And thnx!

Comment: @Lukesprog great answer it worked according to my context. One thing little confusing for me that in `flipper OnClickListener`  I have used 
`flipper.SetInAnimation(this, Android.Resource.Animation.Slide_In_Left); 
flipper.showNext();` and worked perfectly, now what should I do for `flipper.showPrevious();`? I am searching for solution without using  buttons. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you want to do `flipper.showPrevious()` then a button is the way from a user perspective, to go as you used one for the `flipper.showNext()`. Otherwise how should a user get back?

Comment: To built in animations use `android.R.anim.slide_in_left` in Java

Comment: @LucianoMarqueto Gives Error saying Unknown animator name: translate, seems it does not work with fragments.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to control [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper) animation through your XML layout file, then add these attributes to the `ViewFlipper` tag-

```
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
    android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
```

This is a basic example in which the children inside the ViewFlipper slide in and slide out using the default animations provided by android.

You can also provide **your own animation files** by adding these attributes instead of the ones above-

```
    android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_in_left"
```

and then creating these animation files-

In **res/anim/slide_in_left.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0"
            android:toXDelta="-100%p"
            android:duration="500"/>
    </set>
```

In **res/anim/slide_in_right.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="100%p"
            android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="500"/>
    </set>
```

If you would like to start this animation automatically, then add-

```
    android:flipInterval="2000"
    android:autoStart="true"
```

This will start the animation automatically and flip the images (or your views) in every 2 seconds (2000ms).